# Trim the whitespaces in my div of spans

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="target">
  <span>             Last Name              </span>,
  <span> First Name       </span>
</div>
```

I'm getting white space in my generated spans for some unknown reason. Is there a one-liner in jQuery that will tie it together without the whitespace and maybe a space after the comma?

For example,

```
Last Name, First Name
```

The problem is this:

```
$('#target').text().substring(0,30)
```

I'm putting the preceding result in a label.
So in the example above,

I should see the whole `Last Name, First Name`
but instead I'm only seeing 
`Last Name` because of the extra white space.

Comment: What sort of issue are you currently having with your code that attempts this?

Comment: @admdrew I updated OP

Comment: _"for some unknown reason"_ Really? You don't know what's changing your code?

Comment: well, I'm not in control of that part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#target').text().replace(/\s+/g,' ').replace(/ *, */g,', ').trim().substring(0,30)
```

#### Snippet

```js
alert($('#target').text().replace(/\s+/g,' ').replace(/ *, */g,', ').trim().substring(0,30));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <span>             Last Name              </span>,
  <span> First Name       </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it formatted perfectly as you have written it, you have a couple of options. The first one is more complicated but it will actually remove the white-space from the HTML. The second option will just remove it from the extracted string and leave the HTML untouched.

For the first option, you need to use the `text(function)` overload which takes in the current text value and returns the new one.

To handle the spacing around the comma correctly, you actually have to do this twice - once on the `span`s and once on the `div`. Here it is, as requested, in one line, sort of:

```js
// removeSpace replaces multiple whitespaces with a single space
var removeSpace = function(characterIndex, value) { return value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim(); },
    targetText = removeSpace(null,
        $('#target').find('span').text(removeSpace) // handle the spans
            .end().text() // get the div text
    ).substring(0,30);

alert("'" + targetText + "'");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <span>             Last Name              </span>,
  <span> First Name       </span>
</div>
```

The second option is to just do a single regex replace. You will need to use the [match function overload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to remove the spaces before the comma, otherwise you have to do 2 replaces which is much more expensive and more error-prone.

The regex just finds multiple spaces, *optionally* followed by a comma. If a comma is found, then use that as the replacement value, otherwise just return a single space. You can extend the comma matching to include full stops, colons etc

```js
var targetText = $('#target').text().trim()
    .replace(/(\s*)([,\.\:]?)\s*/g, function(all, spaces, punctuation) {
        return punctuation.length > 0 ? punctuation + ' ' :
        spaces.length > 0 ? ' ' : '';
    }).substring(0, 30);

alert("'" + targetText + "'");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <span>             Last Name              </span>,
  <span> First Name       </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first example works great! for me, but I'm having a little hard time following what's going on with a couple things: 1) function(i,v) what does "i" stand for? and doesn't appear to be used? 2) .text(removeSpace) does this mean there is some recursive stuff happening?

Comment: In the first snippet, if the comma was on the line with the second `<span>` , the output would be, "Last Name ,First Name."  In the second snippet, commas are added even if they don't appear within `target`.

Comment: I think a simple search/replace of `$('#target').text()` is all that's needed for this problem.  jQuery uses the native `textContent` if present, otherwise it builds the text content by traversing the element's children.  So there's no need to traverse them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var text = $($('#target').children()[0]).html().trim() + ", " +$($('#target').children()[1]).html().trim();
$("#MyLabel").html( text );
```